# while loading data from Teradata to Oracle using informatica powercenter, we are facing special character issue

Tags: load, informatica

Teradata : JANUVIA - 50MG – TABLET -  1 BLISTER -   28 TABLET (28.TA)
ORacle: JANUVIA - 50MG ? TABLET -  1 BLISTER -   28 TABLET (28.TA)

We are using code page 'ms windows latin 1 (ansi) superset of latin1' for source connection i.e. Teradata.

We are using code page UTF 8 for target

Comment: What's the data type of ports in the mapping? Is it the same for all the transformation this value goes through?

Comment: Can you please paste full error from the log? I've got a feeling this might be source reading error.

Answer (score 0):

The character "–" is a Unicode character [(U+0096)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0096/index.htm). You should change the code page of your source connection to UTF-8. Also, the integration service should be running in Unicode mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Code page at following levels to bring the whole data flow in one character set:
1. Check character set at teradata database (Use Show table)
2. Use the source DB connection of same code page
3. Use the integration service working on same code page
4. Use the target DB connection of same code page
5. Create the target db with same code page

Above I tried to list all the levels where character-set mismatch can occur.

This will ensure as it is transfer of data.